# Should a disconnected CPU fan spin freely if I spin it with my finger?

Tags: fan, cooling

I have an [Arctic Freezer 7 Pro](http://www.arctic-cooling.com/catalog/product_info.php?cPath=1_42&mID=72) CPU cooler that stopped working yesterday after just a few months of use. It doesn't appear to be too dusty, but the fan just won't spin.

In trying to figure out what's wrong, I removed the fan and noticed that it's relatively hard to spin. I don't remember what it was like when I bought it, but it seems reasonable that it should be pretty easy to spin with my finger, or perhaps even by blowing on it.

Am I correct in expecting it to spin freely?

**EDIT**: Thanks for the replies. I'm actually using a desk fan for now, until I can replace the faulty fan. Speedfan says I'm OK...

Comment: Sounds like either a failed bearing or too much gunk gumming up the fan.

Comment: +1 for using the desk fan. Any 80mm case fan will also do. You can affix it using cable ties or wire. It doesn't have to look professional to do a good job. It will allow you to close your case again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should spin freely. I can spin my CPU fan using a vacuum cleaner :)

Comment: As an aside, some say that using a vacuum cleaner isn't a good idea - you could accidentally suck up something important, like jumpers. Blowing is safer. Personally I use a vacuum and air can combo.

Comment: I use a vacuum cleaner at the lowest setting and usually just in the places that I know are safe. Thanks for the tip, anyway!

Answer (score 6):

I've had fans seize up like this in the past.  Replace it quickly, because it's going to cause your computer to overheat.

Answer (score 1):

Go get yourself a little can of [3-in-1 oil](http://www.3inone.com/products/multi-purpose/). Pull the little bearing cover sticker off the fan, put in a drop of oil and reseal it. Give it a few pushes with your finger and see if that gets it back to spinning freely.

I've done that dozens of times with CPU and PC fans and generally have had great luck.

Comment: I've tried this to. It is a temporary fix at best, to buy you time until the new fan you ordered arrives.

Answer (score 0):

You can try applying SILICON OIL and see if it will work. If not, remove it or else it will heat up and add up to the total temperature of the box.